# Review Your Question button not working on iOS 16 on Safari or Chrome

Tags: bug, posting

I am on an iPhone 8 with iOS 16.3.1. The Review Your Question button isn’t working - I press the button and nothing loads. I’ve tried on Safari and Chrome and get the same problem on both.